# How to fetch a part of records from db when using Server-side processing in datatables in Django?

Tags: django, datatables, pagination, server-side

My aim is server-side processing of fetched data with datatables.

My problem is that I can not fetch from db a part of records(ex: 50 per ajax request). For example, when I am giving the limit 50 to define the number of my returning results per page, after the request the paginator returns only 10.

Is there something that I am missing in order to fetch data based on pages of defined records?

My view

```
class ProductSerialNumbersListJSon(LoginRequiredMixin,BaseDatatableView):
# my model
model = ProductSerialNumbers
columns = ['snumber' , 'order','product','registration_date']
order_columns = ['snumber','order','product','registration_date']

def get_initial_queryset(self):
    #fetch the query list from db
    query_list=ProductSerialNumbers.objects.filter(Q(snumber__isnull=True)|Q(order_id__isnull=True)|Q (order_id__finished=0)).order_by("id")
    paginator = Paginator(query_list,50) #50 items per page
    page=int(self.kwargs['page'])

    try:
        result = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        result = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        result = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    product_serials = result.object_list.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
    return ProductSerialNumbers.objects.filter(pk__in=product_serials)
```

My url

```
url(r'^warehouse_tabledata/(?P<page>\d+)/$',views.ProductSerialNumbersListJSon.as_view(), name='warehouse_list_json'),
```

my json result

```
 {"recordsTotal": 50, "recordsFiltered": 50, "draw": 0, "data": [["3", "", "test_proion", "2019-01-16"], ["55", "", "test_proion", "2019-01-16"], ["56", "", "test_proion", "2019-01-16"], ["57", "", "test_proion", "2019-01-16"], ["58", "", "test_proion", "2019-01-16"], ["59", "", "test_proion", "2019-01-16"], ["60", "", "test_proion", "2019-01-16"], ["61", "", "test_proion", "2019-01-16"], ["62", "", "test_proion", "2019-01-16"], ["63", "", "test_proion", "2019-01-16"]], "result": "ok"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are required to add pagination in order to show limited results per page.
django has inbuilt paginator you can do pagination in templates as well.
the below code is from one of my older projects. ignore 'q' as it is just a search query that I was using in my project.

```
paginator = Paginator(query_list, 10) #10 items per page
page = request.GET.get('page') #getting the page number from GET request
try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
context={
    "obj":queryset,
    "title":"Latest Posts",
}
return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

Now in templates

```
<div class="pagination">
<span class="step-links">
    {% if obj.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ obj.previous_page_number }}{% if request.GET.q%}&q={{request.GET.q}}{% endif %}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
        Page {{ obj.number }} of {{ obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>

    {% if obj.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ obj.next_page_number }}{% if request.GET.q%}&q={{request.GET.q}}{% endif %}">next</a>
```

if you want then you can check out this project at [go at line 84 to view full function.](https://github.com/danielhasan1/blogPost/blob/master/posts/views.py)

Comment: useful approach but I got the error count() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). I think this is from try-except block but I do not know how to solve it. This is my approach:      try:
            queryset = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            queryset = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        return queryset

Comment: please add more details or proper sample or traceback error. for example your view modules.